# How to destroy all association data between two models? (Rails beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two models: `store` and `category` with a joining table called `categories.stores`.

How could I delete all relationship data for a store object in the joining table?

Could I use something like one of these:

`store.categories.destroy` or `category.stores.destroy`

**Note:** both models are `has_and_belongs_to_many` (and thus have **no identifier** for each association record -- only store_id and category_id)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association you can either use `delete_all` or `destroy_all`.

In a `has_many` association you should consider using `delete_all` because it deletes records following the `:dependent` strategy (it nullifys foreign keys by default) instead of `destroy_all` which destroys associated records.

More details at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Delete+or+destroy%3F